# jquery-mobile + codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, jquery-mobile

What must be the problem with this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
        <?php 
            echo link_tag('assets/css/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css', 'stylesheet');
            echo script_tag('assets/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js'); 
            echo script_tag('assets/js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js'); 
        ?>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page">
            <header data-role="header">
            <a href="#navigation" data-role="button">Show</a>
            <h3><?php echo $title; ?></h3>
            <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" class="ui-btn-right">
                <a href="#" data-role="button">My Account</a>
                <a href="<?php echo site_url();?>login" data-role="button">Logout</a>                  
            </div>      
        </header>
```

I'am using jquery mobile for my client-side script and PHP(codeigniter) for server-side script.
When I refresh the page after including the  in anchor the page now doesn't display the page anymore.

Can anyone tell what's wrong with the code or I'am just missing something.

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
    class Event_management_c extends CI_Controller {
        public function __construct() {
             parent::__construct();
             $this->load->helper('html', 'url', 'form');
        }

        public function index() {
            $data['title'] = 'Events';
            $data['reply_title'] = 'Reply Message';

            $this->load->view('fragments/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('fragments/nav', $data);
            $this->load->view('events/index', $data);
            $this->load->view('fragments/footer', $data);
        }
     }
    ?>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! If there's anything wrong with the HTML, just try stripping tags till it works and rule out what renders it unable on the mobile. Anybuddy can do this, so why not you?

Comment: thanks u sir for replying
I've done that already, when I remove the php script in the href it works but my issues now is that the link wouldn't be dynamic already.
So when I change for example my server I will have to go into the code again and change it manually

Comment: Try setting [header content type to `text/plain`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) and see if you can find what's going on with the `href=""` property in your mobile.

Comment: All the information after the href are gone. So does the site_url() of codeigniter has the problem?

Comment: It could be you haven't ran `$this->load->helper('url')` and it gives out an fatal error (undefined function), but the error isn't showing due to settings.

Comment: I have added the controller above. It is still the same :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your extra answers from the comments; the problem is most likely that the function `site_url()` isn't defined. The result of this is a fatal error, which isn't shown to you due to settings in php concerning [`error_report`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php).

To solve this, run `$this->load->helper('url')` in relevant controller, or simply add `url` to the helper array in `application/config/autoload.php`. Since this function is so common, I recommend to autoload it.

Comment: Thanks sir Robin it worked :)
But why isn't it working when I just load the helper in the constructor of the controller?
Is there any difference from auto loading it and loading it in the controller?

Comment: Only if you run it after `$this->load->view()`. That is, after it's trying to execute `site_url()`. In this case you need: `$this->load->helper(array('html', 'url', 'form'));` note the `array()`,

Comment: Oh how stupid of me to forget that :)
thanks sir for the help I appreciate it

Comment: You're welcome. If my answer helped with your case, mark it as Accepted to help other users find the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

Problem here

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url();?>login" data-role="button">Logout</a>
```

to

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url();?>/login" data-role="button">Logout</a>
```

you can use template library for codeigniter like [TEMPLATE LIBRARY](http://www.williamsconcepts.com/ci/libraries/template/index.html)

and reload the script and style files.

Comment: CodeIgniter has as a rule to always append `/` to it's addresses. This is most likely not the problem.